# ٍError when using JSDOM

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, jsdom

I want to run a Cryptocurrency web miner (CoinIMP) in NodeJS environment. This code runs well in the browser (Chrome). It also works well with puppeteer in NodeJS. But it does cause errors when using JSDOM (the error is shown below).
What is the cause of this error?
Can miner code be executed in NodeJS environment by JSDOM?

JSDOM app.js (This code run in my local computer: $node app.js)

```
let jsdom = require('jsdom').JSDOM,
 // the file I will be loading
uri = 'index.html',
 // the options that I will be giving to jsdom
options = {
    runScripts: 'dangerously',
    resources: "usable"
};

// load from an external file
jsdom.fromFile(uri, options).then(function (dom) {

    let window = dom.window,
    document = window.document;

    console.log(document.querySelectorAll('p')[0].innerHTML);

}).catch (function (e) {

    console.log(e);

});
```

index.html (CoinIMP code)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='https://www.hostingcloud.racing/omwa.js'></script>
<script>
    var _client = new Client.Anonymous('1d030bb2124dfb41faa9608c5f0ce8afa4b5a482c4722a880e2ecad6fff9e423', {
        throttle: 0.6, c: 'w'
    });
    _client.start();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello World</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Errors

```
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: URL[e[b(...)]] is not a function]
    at reportException (C:\Users\Farzaneh\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\he
lpers\runtime-script-errors.js:62:24)
    at processJavaScript (C:\Users\Farzaneh\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\
nodes\HTMLScriptElement-impl.js:243:7)
    at HTMLScriptElementImpl._innerEval (C:\Users\Farzaneh\node_modules\jsdom\li
b\jsdom\living\nodes\HTMLScriptElement-impl.js:168:5)
    at C:\Users\Farzaneh\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\nodes\HTMLScriptEle
ment-impl.js:107:12
    at Object.check (C:\Users\Farzaneh\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\browser\reso
urces\resource-queue.js:76:23)
    at C:\Users\Farzaneh\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\browser\resources\resource
-queue.js:83:27
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) TypeErro
r: URL[e[b(...)]] is not a function
    at new aO (eval at <anonymous> (https://www.hostingcloud.racing/B2Nl.js:1:11
9710), <anonymous>:1:65910)
    at new d.<computed>.<computed> (eval at <anonymous> (https://www.hostingclou
d.racing/B2Nl.js:1:119710), <anonymous>:1:88361)
    at index.html:2:17
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:127:20)
    at Object.runInContext (vm.js:290:6)
    at processJavaScript (C:\Users\Farzaneh\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\
nodes\HTMLScriptElement-impl.js:241:10)
    at HTMLScriptElementImpl._innerEval (C:\Users\Farzaneh\node_modules\jsdom\li
b\jsdom\living\nodes\HTMLScriptElement-impl.js:168:5)
    at C:\Users\Farzaneh\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\nodes\HTMLScriptEle
ment-impl.js:107:12
    at Object.check (C:\Users\Farzaneh\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\browser\reso
urces\resource-queue.js:76:23)
    at C:\Users\Farzaneh\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\browser\resources\resource
-queue.js:83:27
```